# Dell PC won't boot with new RAM, unless it's paired with old RAM

Tags: boot, memory, dual-channel

I did a search but can't find this exact issue.
I bought 2 x 16GB of G.Skill RAM. Identical sticks, same timing as old ram.

Dell Inspiron 3891:

Will boot with factory ram, 8GB.
Will boot with some old ram, 4GB.
Will boot with both together.

Won't boot 1 stick of new G.Skill RAM (tested both sticks, both slots).
Won't boot 2 sticks of new G.Skill RAM.

**WILL** boot with 1 old stick + 1 new stick.

Any combination of sticks and slots works, as long as at least one old stick is present. So is it having a problem when it tries to activate dual channel? I can't see any way to disable that in Dell BIOS.

BIOS log did have a note about shutdown due to 'thermal event' but not sure if that was due to the ram or having to unplug the PSU (stupid Dell PSU doesn't have on/off switch and will try to run continously while plugged in).

Comment: Check memory configurations and specifications in this pdf>>>https://dl.dell.com/content/manual28565828-inspiron-3891-setup-and-specifications.pdf?language=en-us&ps=true

Comment: If nothing works, buy a different brand of memory.

Comment: Memory density compatibility is a concern on older hardware. There simply isn’t enough information to identify the specifications of the hardware in question. Dell has far to many conflicting configurations to identity what hardware you have specifically. What exactly is “it” that your trying to disable?

Comment: @Moab I checked specs before buying and nothing in the specs indicates this Ram would not work. But it looks like I'll be stuck buying a different brand. But it's strange I can get one stick to work.

Comment: @Ramhound Welpp, I ended up returning and exchanging for Crucial brand memory. People said online that this is the brand that's most compatible with dells, and it seems they're right, it works. Although the first boot hung after the "alert, memory has changed" warning, second boot hung, and third boot got into windows and is fine so far. I guess it comes down to the timing and voltage or something.

Comment: @CreeDorofl - Intel or AMD?  Memory training works differently between Intel and AMD

Comment: @Ramhound Intel

Answer (score 0):

I returned and replaced with a brand that was said to be compatible, Crucial (aka Micron), and that worked. If anyone is trying to upgrade same/similar machine, the exact info is: SKU: 153577 - Mfr Part #: CT2K16G4DFRA32A - UPC: 649528903631 - Kit CT2K16G4DFRA32A

I sort of thought that if you get the right generation and clock speed, you should be good to go, but that's apparently not the case. The timing and voltage are different, and I suspect the slight difference in power draw isn't the problem, so it must be the timing. When I paired with the older sticks of ram, the new ram must have been forced to run at the slower speed of the older ram, and that's a speed the Dell can handle. But if I use ONLY the new ram, it's trying to run at the faster speed and failing. And with no XMP support for most dells, that means I can't change it and make it slow down.

*Ram that doesn't work:*
Voltage: 1.35V
CAS Latency: 16
Memory Latency Timings: 16-18-18-38

*Ram that works:*
Voltage: 1.2V
CAS Latency: 22
Memory Latency Timings: 22-22-22